# Combinatorics identity algebra

Tags: combinatorics

How does $2n\choose n$ + $2n\choose n-1$ = $2n+1\choose n$? I know that $n\choose k$ = $n\choose n-k$

Comment: If you need an intuition as to why this is the case, consider the scenario where you have $2n+1$ objects and you need to choose $n$ of them. This identity says the number of ways of choosing $n$ from $2n+1$ is the same as the number of ways of choosing $n$ from $2n$ added to the number of ways of choosing $n-1$ from $2n$.  This is the case because you can think of the LHS as saying "you can either have a specific object in your choices or not. If it's in the set of $n$, you get $2n$ choose $n-1$. If it's not, you still have $n$ to choose from the $2n$."

Comment: ok thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use that $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
Using this definition we get
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!\times n!}+\frac{2n)!}{(n-1)!\times(n+1)!}$$

Comment: confusing me badly

Comment: He's suggesting that you write about each of the terms you have in terms of factorials, and he's providing the definition of $n$ choose $k$.

Comment: alright, thanks very much